# How to keep soft keyboard from opening on activity launch in Android?

Tags: android

In an Android app, whenever the activity launches, the textbox gets the focus and the soft keyboard pops up automatically. I have tried to stop this by using following line in onCreate method, but it does not work.

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(EditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove auto focus/keyboard popup of a field when the screen shows up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892615/how-to-remove-auto-focus-keyboard-popup-of-a-field-when-the-screen-shows-up)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

I know this is old but maybe it will help someone in the future...

I haven't seen anyone suggest "stateHidden"

[From the Android docs - android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Your manifest file would look like:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
    ...
>
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use the following line of code to make sure the keyboard only pops up when a user clicks into an EditText

**Java**

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

**Kotlin**

```
window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)
```

And as someone answered me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2562066/):

You need to add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

to your activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: This works, but when I click the text box for typing, the keyboard pops up over the text box an I can't see what I am typing. The text box is at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: You need to add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to your tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" is set in AndroidManifest.xml but still same problem.

There is a button in same screen too. I tried to move focus to the button by using:

btn.setFocusable(true);
btn.requestFocus();

But still the focus is on TextView. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Strange, can you post your code? The activity tag from the manifest and the code from your UI Activity?

Comment: I am going to post the code as an answer of this question, as code formatting is not available in comments.

Answer (score 3):

Does the following work?

```
// Find editor
EditText editWindowInstance = this.findViewById(R.id.MyEditWindow);

// close soft keyboard 
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(editWindowInstance.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: How about using "hideSoftInputFromWindow(editWindowInstance, ...)" instead of "editWindowInstance.getWindowToken()"?

Answer (score 2):

You can put this code in your Activity.onCreate:
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

But I found that the most reliable and clean way was to simply set the focus onto to a different view, in your activity XML Layout

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/mybutton">
  <requestFocus />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work perfectly, try this

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

And add the following to your manifest.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked for me. Finally a very easy solution worked like magic. 
Add these two lines in your parent layout.

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me

```
((InputMethodManager) iClockActivity
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                    .showSoftInput(textView, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
This works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).