# Android Keyboard automatically appears for EditText when activity is created

Tags: android

I have a single activity class and it has a two EditTexts on the screen.  When the activity launches the keyboard launches with it.  Why is this?  I did not request enter anything yet into the edit box. Why does it do this? And how can I get rid of this behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup

Comment: terrible default behavior for a screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your stateHidden in the manifest file for the activity:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

and this might be helpful:

[How to keep soft keyboard from opening on activity launch in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037375/how-to-keep-soft-keyboard-from-opening-on-activity-launch-in-android)

Comment: Yes, needs to have stateHidden set as outlined plus this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);  set in the create method.