# android: don't show soft keyboard automatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHolder"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This produces:

[image]

Now, when user presses the show background apps button at the bottom (as shown in above picture), and when user comes back to the app, the soft keyboard gets shown.

[image]

I don't want the soft keyboard to be shown in this case.

How can this be done?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5295050/1288725)

Comment: @MehulJoisar thanks,  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" in activity manifest worked

Comment: I'm glad to help you. Plz search properly before posting the question, it will save your time a lot and it will keep this website clean as well with unique questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, add the below attribute for the entry of this `Activity`:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

It is not supposed to be written in your layout XML, but the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

To set more than one soft input modes, you can set it like:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

For more information, you can refer the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" in activity manifest worked

Comment: @user5155835 You can accept the answer if your query is resolved.