# Keyboard popup for editText should not push the UI and draw on top

Tags: android, keyboard, android-manifest

After searching many related threads , i am posting this question .

My problem is that when i click on the editText box the Keyboard popup pushes the UI and the keyboard draws at the bottom rather i want the keyboard to draw over my UI and according to [Android - Adjust screen when keyboard pops up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559273/android-adjust-screen-when-keyboard-pops-up)

I tried  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in my manifest file but that didnt solve my problem . Again i get the same issue .

Is there any other solution , any related answers are welcomed . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, add the following line under the activity with the keyboard:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Duplicate: [Keyboard Showed messed up elements' position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233857/keyboard-showed-messed-up-elements-position/13399338#13399338)

Comment: No bro. that also didnt helped me . . .

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, and even though

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

should work, try putting the following code instead, in the onCreate() method of your activity:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Insted of ..

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Try this..

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: It worked for me... just to be sure... u added it to the right activity right in manifest right..

Comment: yes . Also that i have added it to all the activities . . . .

Comment: on what device you are running this ?

Comment: I run it on galaxy s3 and xperia tipo